# Why these two Java objects do not equals?

Tags: java, equals

I was make some code and found that objects ar eno equals - it is trivial question but not understand how default equals works.

```
class A {
    String id;
    public A(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        A a = new A("1");
        A b = new A("1");
        System.out.println(a.id);
        System.out.println(b.id);
        System.out.println(a.equals(b));
    }
}
```

Result is:

```
1
1
false
```

But I want to have `a.equals(b) == true` why it is `false`?

Comment: You need to override `.equals()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class currently extends only `Object` class and in Object class `equals` method looks like this

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return (this == obj);
}
```

What you need is to override this method, for example like this

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    A other = (A) obj;
    if (id == other.id)
        return true;
    if (id == null)
        return false;
    if (other.id == null)
        return false;
    if (!this.id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Also when you override `equals` you probably should override `hashCode` method, but this is not subject of your question. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java).

Comment: Fixed other.id is failing before (null.id -> null exception).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't override equals() on the object, you are comparing two different memory references. So override equals() to compare the id fields.

Comment: Good hint but @Pschemo has full solution.

Answer (score 1):

It overrides `Object`'s `equals` method by default, it checks the "same object" rather than "same content". If you want to have `a.equals(b) == true`, you should override it:

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof A) {
        A a = (A) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            return a.id == null;
        } else {
            return id.equals(a.id);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

----- EDITED -----

Comment: Good but code is not clear (not for me) - improve code style you could be good but not readable.

Comment: Some bugs in code since null of obj + null of this.is or obj.id.

Comment: Good but still code style is ugly (could be faster too) - it is good advice for you the most important in writing large program is readability not code compression - it is major factor of quality. You focus on compression of code (side effect is complication and hard to understand code or review it) change it since it blocks development.

Comment: Some example `!obj.getClass().equals(A.class)` better is simple `obj.getClass() != A.getClass())` (who know what do equals, why to check it, why negate result).

Comment: Some redundancy `if (id == null) return id == ((A) obj).id;` == `if (id == null) return id == obj.id;` better is `if (id == null && obj.id == null) return true; else return false;` more clear *not need understand transition* (if id == null so id == obj.id mean obj.id == null faster reading/review - avoid logic puzzles as much as possible. Maybe I help you little.

Comment: @Chameleon, `obj.id` is wrong. `obj` is type of `Object`, not `A`. You have to cast it.

Comment: @Chameleon, Also, instead of compare their `Class`, it is better to use `instanceof` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you should rewrite an equals() method for your code, as you would a toString() method.